# Changed find_library behavior from CMake 2.8 to CMake 3.2

Tags: cmake

I have got the following problem while migrating from CMake 2.8.x to 3.2.x. Thereby, it seems that the internal behavior of `find_library` changed. Here is a minimal example which demonstrates my problem.

Consider that we are search for library called `libopenblas.so` which is located in `/scratch/local_install/lib` and `/usr/lib/openblas-base`. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable is set to `/scratch/local_install/lib`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` file is the following:

```
PROJECT(TEST) 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(_libname "openblas") 
SET(_libdir  ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH "/usr/lib/openblas-base")

find_library(OPENBLAS_LIBRARY
      NAMES ${_libname}
      HINTS ${_libdir}
      PATHS ${_libdir}
      )
MESSAGE("OPENBLAS: ${OPENBLAS_LIBRARY}")
```

If I execute this using CMake 2.8.7 or 2.8.12, I get

```
OPENBLAS: /scratch/koehlerm/local_install/lib/libopenblas.so
```

If I configure the code using CMake 3.2.1, I get

```
OPENBLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so
```

which I only want to get if there is none `libopenblas.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. How can I restore the old behavior of CMake 2.8.x even if the code is configured with CMake 3.2.x?

Comment: Can you be more precise what you mean by 2.8.x? The version number scheme changes. With 2.8 the third digit introduces new features. If you really compare 2.8.7 with 3.2, the newer is seven releases newer!

Comment: I checked cmake 2.8.6 and cmake 2.8.12 and they behave in the same way, thats why I said cmake 2.8.x. From my personal experience I never observed the second behavior with and version of the 2.8. series.

Comment: Have you ever cleaned your build directory / CMakeCache. I think this behavior dates back to some 2.8.10 (?) version at least. I don't remember any more.

Comment: I started everytime from a clean directory. As mentioned in the comments of the first answer the NO_DEFAULT_PATH option introduces a strange behavior in CMake 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` for `find_library`, then it will ignore the default location. See the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/find_library.html).

To get the bahvior you want, use find_library twice. First with NO_DEFAULT_PATH and after that without. If it is found the first time, the result is cached and the second call including the default path is skipped. If nothing is found first, it will be re-run and look at the default paths, too.

Comment: Interestingly the documentation if the search order does not change from cmake 2.8.7 to 3.2.1 but the behavior of the function did.  And none of the two libraries reside in a standard path so only using the DEFAULT_PATH does not give me any library. The difference seems to be that the order how the paths are picked from the HINTS and the PATHS section has been changed.

Comment: Furthermore using NO_DEFAULT_PATH seems to reverse the order of the values in ${_libdir} when they are used in FIND_LIBRARY