# CMake find_path behavior change between CMake 2.8.12 and 3.7.2

Tags: cmake, version

I have a `find_path` call that provides a `PATHS` option. In CMake 2.8.12 it returns the provided path whereas in CMake 3.7.2 it returns `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` (or some other CMake content that happens to be that directory).

The `find_path` (third-party) snippet looks like this:

```
set(ZLIB_SEARCH_PATH "${PATH_ETC}/src")
set(ZLIB_SRC_DIR_NAME "zlib")
set(ZLIB_PATH_INIT "${ZLIB_SEARCH_PATH}/${ZLIB_SRC_DIR_NAME}")

find_path(ZLIB_PATH
    NAMES CMakeLists.txt  
    PATHS "${ZLIB_PATH_INIT}" 
    DOC "Location of zLib source")
```

While [Changed find_library behavior from CMake 2.8 to CMake 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365959/changed-find-library-behavior-from-cmake-2-8-to-cmake-3-2) provides the working hint to add the `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` option it isn't a solution to me as I'm including third-party software and I'd like to understand the root cause of the change.

Note that all of the following variables are empty / unset:

- CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE
- CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
- CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH
- CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH
- CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.

What is the behavior change? Is there a way to "debug into" the `find_path` call?

Comment: Show exact `find_path` call. Or, better, [mcve], so we don't need to guess about content of variety number of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no "debug into" the `find_path` call method besides debugging into CMake itself.

And the search order was definitely not changed by purpose. The only related commit I could find was ["find_*: Fix search order when the environment duplicates some HINTS"](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/02440154fb457e481d44aa0a2c2134e1a66e0f4b). You could try replacing `PATHS` with `HINTS` keyword and see if it makes things better.

If the above call would be your own code, don't use `find_path` when you already know the path (`ZLIB_PATH_INIT`).

If the code is not yours, you can always use [`CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH.html) to remove local files from the search list:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

Comment: Thanks Florian, all answer parts apply: Replacing PATHS with HINTS solves the issue and/or adding ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} to CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH. Last but not least find_path is used by the third-party CMake system to allow for the use of another zlib than the default one.

Comment: I'll eventually bring the third-party supplier to replace PATHS with HINTS to follow the CMake find_path documentation's recommendation: "Search the paths specified by the HINTS option. These should be paths computed by system introspection, such as a hint provided by the location of another item already found. Hard-coded guesses should be specified with the PATHS option".

Comment: @RolandSarrazin You're welcome. And for the third-party software I would raise another issue: Just searching for `CMakeLists.txt` is not very `ZLIB` specific. It could find anything. I would recommend using CMake's [`FindZLIB module`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html) if `${ZLIB_SEARCH_PATH}/${ZLIB_SRC_DIR_NAME}/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't exist.